# Hadoop Cluster Deployment Using Pivotal

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to deploy Hadoop cluster via Pivotal distribution.

For the same, I am following link mentioned below
http://pivotalhd.docs.pivotal.io/doc/2100/webhelp/topics/ManuallyInstallingandUsingPivotalHD21Stack.html

Deployment Configuration:
1) phd1.xyz.com - NameNode, ResourceManager
2) phd2.xyz.com - DataNode, NodeManager

I have above mentioned services UP and Running and also able to access the HDFS file system but not able to execute jobs on cluster

Above provided link doesn't mention if the job has to be executed via root or hdfs user, so I tried both the ways

1. Error when job is executed via root user

> hadoop jar/usr/lib/gphd/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0-gphd-3.1.0.0.jar
>   pi 2 200

The following error occurring:

```
>     Number of Maps  = 2
>     Samples per Map = 200
>     org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE,
> inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:234)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:214)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:158)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5389)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5371)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5345)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3583)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3553)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3525)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:745)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:550)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:63031)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
>             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>             at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)
>     
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>             at
```

2. Error when job is executed via hdfs user

> ```
> sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /usr/lib/gphd/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0-gphd-3.1.0.0.jar pi 2 200
> ```

the following error ocurring:

```
> Number of Maps  = 2
>     Samples per Map = 200
>     Wrote input for Map #0
>     Wrote input for Map #1
>     Starting Job
>     15/01/01 20:48:20 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at phd1.xyz.com/10.44.189.6:8050
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.map.speculative
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.job.output.value.class
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.reduce.speculative
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.job.map.class
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.job.reduce.class
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.job.output.key.class
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use
> mapreduce.job.working.dir
>     15/01/01 20:48:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1420122968684_0002
>     15/01/01 20:48:22 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1420122968684_0002 to ResourceManager at
> phd1.xyz.com/10.44.189.6:8050
>     15/01/01 20:48:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://phd1.persistent.co.in:8088/proxy/application_1420122968684_0002/
>     15/01/01 20:48:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1420122968684_0002
>     15/01/01 20:48:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1420122968684_0002 running in uber mode : false
>     15/01/01 20:48:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
>     15/01/01 20:48:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1420122968684_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application
> application_1420122968684_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for
> appattempt_1420122968684_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 due to:
> Exception from container-launch:
>     org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>     
>     
>     .Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
>     15/01/01 20:48:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
>     Job Finished in 5.973 seconds
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://phd1.xyz.com:8020/user/hdfs/QuasiMonteCarlo_1420125497811_11863122/out/reduce-out
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1112)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1112)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1749)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1773)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:314)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: After enabling log generation for yarn, I am able to view error in stderr file, which provides me a short but relevant error description.Error i

Comment: How do you enable log generation for yarn? Your question and answer is not much help in its current state.